# Adding Metadata to Sharepoint File Graph-API Java SDK- Invalid Request. But GET() works, PUT/PATCH() does not

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, sharepoint-api

Here is the calling code. Followed by the method that is supposed to add MetaData to the file I just uploaded through Sharepoint within our code.

```
    Map<String, String> metaDataValues = new HashMap<>()
    metaDataValues.put("DocumentType", "Contract")
    metaDataValues.put("User", oidcUser.userEntity.id)
    addMetadataToFile(oidcUser, file.id, metaDataValues)
```

This is the method it calls and when I PUT or PATCH it returns Invalid Request and I have no idea why.

```
private addMetadataToFile(OidcUser oidcUser, String itemId, Map<String, String> metaData) {
    FieldValueSet fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet()
    metaData.each {data -> {
        fieldValueSet.additionalDataManager().put(data.key, new JsonPrimitive(data.value))
    }}

    FieldValueSet getting = graphServiceClient.groups(oidcUser.defaultGroupId)
            .drive()
            .items(itemId)
            .listItem()
            .fields()
            .buildRequest()
    .get()

    // If you can get, then the following should work to update.

    graphServiceClient.groups(oidcUser.defaultGroupId)
            .drive()
            .items(itemId)
            .listItem()
            .fields()
            .buildRequest()
            .put(fieldValueSet)
}
```

I have spent too many hours trying any combination and nothing ever seems to work. I am exhausted. Any help to find out why it fails?

Comment: where you ever able to solve this?
I also need to add metadata tags to a file to use in search, any tips

Comment: Nope. Instead we are putting this information in our database instead.